# Ionic2 always show left menu

Tags: ionic2

I am working on an mobile app with Ionic2. When I navigate using navController.push(SomePage) method, I get back button. I want to show left menu button always and disable back button. How can I achieve that?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out that rather to use

```
navController.setRoot(somePage);
```

with parameter

```
navController.setRoot(somePage, {"id" : 123});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hideBackButton attribute to hide the back button when push is used.
Ref - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/navbar/Navbar/
For example:
`<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
     ...
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>`

Comment: This hides the menu button too